# Position title above plot area in R plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have a `plotly` plot where the title is placed in the plot area by default. I would like to change this to have the plot title outside of the plot area.

[image]

In the screenshot, the title is in the "plot area" (light grey), I would like this to be above the plot area.

My current code only has the `title` argument in the plot `layout`:

```
plt <- plt %>% 
layout(
    title = sprintf('Ice-formation Risk <br>%s', 
                    format(Sys.time(),format = '%d %b %Y %H:%M %Z')))
```

I've tried playing with some of the parameters indicated in `plotly` [reference](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#layout-title) without success:

```
plt <- plt %>% 
layout(
  title = list(
    text = sprintf('Ice-formation Risk <br>%s', 
                   format(Sys.time(),format = '%d %b %Y %H:%M %Z')),
    xref = 'paper', yref = 'paper',
    color = 'rgb(17,17,17)'
  )
)
```

The moment I change the `title` attribute from a string to a `list`, the plot title vanishes. I've experimented with removing the `xref` and `yref` parameters and leaving only the `text` attribute with the same result.

**Sample Code**

```
plot1 <- plot_ly(iris) %>% 
  layout(
    title = list(
      text = 'sample plot', xref = 'x', yref = 'y', x = 0.5, y = 1, color = 'rgb(217,83,79)'
    ),
    margin = list( pad = 50, b = 90, l = 130, r = 50 ),
    yaxis = list(
      showline = F, side = 'left', title = 'Axis1', color = 'black', 
      overlaying = 'y3', zeroline = F
    ),
    yaxis2 = list(
      tickfont = list(color = "black"), showline = F, overlaying = "y3", side = "right",
      title = "Axis2", zeroline = F, anchor = 'free', position = 1
    ),
    yaxis3 = list(
      tickfont = list(color = "black"), side = "left", title = "Axis3", 
      zeroline = F, anchor = 'free'
    )
  ) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~Sepal.Width, y = ~Sepal.Length, name = 'Sepal Length', color = ~Species,
            type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers') %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~Sepal.Width, y = ~Petal.Length, name = 'Petal Length', color = ~Species,
            type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', yaxis = 'y2') %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~Sepal.Width, y = ~Petal.Width, name = 'Petal Width', color = ~Species,
            type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', yaxis = 'y3')
```

The plot `title` still vanishes. I have three y-axes in there because my actual plot needs to have three. The `margin` values were "tweaked" to get the axis labels to show properly, else they overlap and are unreadable.

[image]

Comment: try `xref='x',x=0.5,yref='y',y=1`. The title needs to be a list. If you need more help then please create a minimal, reproducable example or share the code for your `plt` object.

Comment: @5th added some sample code. The `xref` and `yref` parameters did not work - the title just vanishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is really odd. Usually the reference is quite accurate. I submitted an issue to [Github](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1451). Especially since the documentation on the [project website](https://plot.ly/r/text-and-annotations/#text-mode) still uses `title="some string"`.

Anyways for the moment I recommend you use the `annotations` option instead. This one works like it is described in the reference ;) 
It is a bit of a hack though. If you put `yshift` too high it escapes. I hope it helps anyways:

```
plot_ly(iris) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Sepal.Width, y = ~Sepal.Length, name = 'Sepal Length', color = ~Species,
            type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers') %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~Sepal.Width, y = ~Petal.Length, name = 'Petal Length', color = ~Species,
            type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', yaxis = 'y2') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Sepal.Width, y = ~Petal.Width, name = 'Petal Width', color = ~Species,
            type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', yaxis = 'y3') %>%
  layout(
       margin = list( pad = 50, b = 90, l = 130, r = 50 ),
    yaxis = list(
      showline = F, side = 'left', title = 'Axis1', color = 'black' ,
      overlaying = 'y3', zeroline = F
    ),
    yaxis2 = list(
      tickfont = list(color = "black"), showline = F, overlaying = "y3", side = "right",
      title = "Axis2", zeroline = F, anchor = 'free', position = 1
    ),
    yaxis3 = list(
      tickfont = list(color = "black"), side = "left", title = "Axis3",
      zeroline = F, anchor = 'free'
    ),annotations=list(text="sample text",xref="paper",x=0.5,
                      yref="paper",y=1,yshift=30,showarrow=FALSE, 
                      font=list(size=24,color='rgb(217,83,79)'))
  )
```

Looks like this: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I have this workaround already, just that it's not very elegant. On a side note, is there a reference that can explain the parameters used in `plotly` - I find the reference is not very descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use `title.text` until the R package upgrades to plotly.js 1.43 or higher

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/releases/tag/v1.43.0

https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/pull/1450