# Plotly: How to prevent title from overlapping the plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, plotly

Here is code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 1',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[3, 6, 4],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[1, 0.5, 1.5]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 2',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[4, 7, 3],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[0.5, 1, 2]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.update_layout(barmode='group',
                  title=dict(
                            text = "Some <br> title <br> here",
                            x = 0.5,
                            y = 0.95,
                            xanchor =  'center',
                            yanchor = 'top',
                            #pad = dict(
                            #            t = 0
                            #           ),
                            font = dict(
                                        #family='Courier New, monospace',
                                        size = 40,
                                        #color='#000000'
                                        )
                            ))


fig.show()
```

This is output:

[image]

**Question:** How to properly align title here without reducing plot title font size?

*Of course this is just example and actual plot will look differently. Main idea of the question is to get the solution for proper aliment of titles with big size of the font.*

Comment: Increasing the figure size seems a likely solution. [Setting Graph Size in Python](https://plotly.com/python/setting-graph-size/)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I tried but it does not helped. The figure is stretching.

Comment: Example for R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54131048/position-title-above-plot-area-in-r-plotly

Comment: Also for R: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821171/fix-plotly-ggplotly-title-overlapping-plot-when-title-is-split-on-two-lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An adjustment of the margins along with a small adjustment of `y=0.95` should do the trick:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 1',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[3, 6, 4],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[1, 0.5, 1.5]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 2',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[4, 7, 3],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[0.5, 1, 2]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.update_layout(barmode='group',
                  title=dict(
                            text = "Some <br> title <br> here",
                            x = 0.5,
                            y = 0.90,
                            xanchor =  'center',
                            yanchor = 'top',
                            #pad = dict(
                            #            t = 0
                            #           ),
                            font = dict(
                                        #family='Courier New, monospace',
                                        size = 40,
                                        #color='#000000'
                                        )
                            ))

fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=50, r=50, t=200, b=50),paper_bgcolor="LightSteelBlue")
fig.show()
```

Comment: Just to clarify, we are adjusting here margin of the graphical part of the plot, not the margin of the plot title, correct?

Comment: Also someone can find it useful: Only `margin = dict(t = 200)` does the job too.